# Erlang code to measure time operations took to execute?

Tags: erlang

Could somebody be so kind as to point me towards some erlang code which allows me to time how long it takes to run certain pieces of code?

I havent seen an erlang library where this is available?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`erlang:statistics`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#statistics-1) function.

This is used in Joe Armstrong's Programming Erlang book (p141).

e.g.

```
yourfun() ->

    statistics(runtime),
    statistics(wall_clock),

    % your code here

    {_, Time1} = statistics(runtime),
    {_, Time2} = statistics(wall_clock),
    U1 = Time1 * 1000,
    U2 = Time2 * 1000,
    io:format("Code time=~p (~p) microseconds~n",
    [U1,U2]).
```

In this example `U1` is the CPU time and `U2` is the total elapsed time (wall clock time).

Comment: +1. @mezamorphic do digg into the erlang docs to see the difference between `runtime`, `wall_clock`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

There is the [timer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html) library; check [tc/[1-3]](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1).

You can also use [erlang:now/0](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0) to collect timestamps and then calculate the duration ([now_diff/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#now_diff-2) is really useful for that).

Answer (score 5):

```
 Take a look at timer:tc(Module, Function, Arguments)
```