# Testing Erlang function performance with timer

Tags: performance, timer, erlang

I'm testing the performance of a function in a tight loop (say 5000 iterations) using `timer:tc/3`:

```
{Duration_us, _Result} = timer:tc(M, F, [A])
```

This returns both the duration (in microseconds) and the result of the function. For argument's sake the duration is N microseconds.

I then perform a simple average calculation on the results of the iterations.

If I place a `timer:sleep(1)` function call **before** the `timer:tc/3` call, the average duration for all the iterations is always > the average without the sleep:

```
timer:sleep(1),
timer:tc(M, F, [A]).
```

This doesn't make much sense to me as the `timer:tc/3` function should be atomic and not care about anything that happened before it.

Can anyone explain this strange functionality? Is it somehow related to scheduling and reductions?

Comment: The `erlang:statistics` function may be useful to you in performance testing; http://stackoverflow.com/a/13381546/1461850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

4> foo:foo(10000).

Where:

```
-module(foo).
-export([foo/1, baz/1]).

foo(N) -> TL = bar(N), {TL,sum(TL)/N} .

bar(0) -> [];
bar(N) ->
    timer:sleep(1),
    {D,_} = timer:tc(?MODULE, baz, [1000]),
    [D|bar(N-1)]
    .

baz(0) -> ok;
baz(N) -> baz(N-1).

sum([]) -> 0;
sum([H|T]) -> H + sum(T).
```

I tried this, and it's interesting. With the sleep statement the mean time returned by timer:tc/3 is 19 to 22 microseconds, and with the sleep commented out, the average drops to 4 to 6 microseconds. Quite dramatic!

I notice there are artefacts in the timings, so events like this (these numbers being the individual microsecond timings returned by timer:tc/3) are not uncommon:

```
---- snip ----
  5,5,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,
  5,6,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,
  5,5,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,7,8,7,8,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,
  14,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,
  5,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,
  4,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,
  5,5,54,22,26,21,22,22,24,24,32,31,36,31,33,27,25,21,22,21,
  24,21,22,22,24,21,22,21,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,21,24,21,22,21,
  23,27,22,21,24,21,22,21,24,22,22,21,23,22,22,21,24,22,22,21,
  24,21,22,22,24,22,22,21,24,22,22,22,24,22,22,22,24,22,22,22,
  24,22,22,22,24,22,22,21,24,22,22,21,24,21,22,22,24,22,22,21,
  24,21,23,21,24,22,23,21,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,22,
  24,22,23,21,24,21,23,21,23,21,21,21,23,21,25,22,24,21,22,21,
  24,21,22,21,24,22,21,24,22,22,21,24,22,23,21,23,21,22,21,23,
  21,22,21,23,21,23,21,24,22,22,22,24,22,22,41,36,30,33,30,35,
  21,23,21,25,21,23,21,24,22,22,21,23,21,22,21,24,22,22,22,24,
  22,22,21,24,22,22,22,24,22,22,21,24,22,22,21,24,22,22,21,24,
  22,22,21,24,21,22,22,27,22,23,21,23,21,21,21,23,21,21,21,24,
  21,22,21,24,21,22,22,24,22,22,22,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,21,24,
  21,23,21,23,21,22,21,23,21,23,22,24,22,22,21,24,21,22,22,24,
  21,23,21,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,21,24,21,22,22,24,
  22,22,22,24,22,22,21,24,22,21,21,24,21,22,22,24,21,22,22,24,
  24,23,21,24,21,22,24,21,22,21,23,21,22,21,24,21,22,21,32,31,
  32,21,25,21,22,22,24,46,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,
  6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,
  5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,6,5,5,5,
  5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,
  5,5,5,4,5,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
  6,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,
  5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,
---- snip ----
```

I assume this is the effect you are referring to, though when you say **always > N**, is it **always**, or just mostly? Not always for me anyway.

The above results extract was without the sleep. Typically when using sleep timer:tc/3 returns low times like 4 or 5 most of the time without the sleep, but sometimes big times like 22, and with the sleep in place it's usually big times like 22, with occasional batches of low times.

It's certainly not obvious why this would happen, since sleep really just means yield. I wonder if all this is not down to the CPU cache. After all, especially on a machine that's not busy, one might expect the case without the sleep to execute most of the code all in one go without it getting moved to another core, without doing so much else with the core, thus making the most out of the caches... but when you sleep, and thus yield, and come back later, the chances of cache hits might be considerably less.

Comment: Yes - that's pretty much the general idea. I've looked again and I'm averaging the result - this is more in-line with what you're seeing. I've updated the question to reflect the fact that I'm using averages.

Comment: Yes, I started out with an average of course, until I realised that the raw data had artefacts, and thus was just as interesting as the averages.

Comment: Question on the last sentence: "when you sleep, and thus yield, and come back later, the chances of cache hits might be considerably less." 

Why was the clause "especially on a machine that's not busy" added? Isn't it  even _more_ likely to have a cache miss on a machine that _is_ busy, all else being equal?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring performance is a complex task especially on new HW and in modern OS. There are many things which can fiddle with your result. First thing, you are not alone. It is when you measure on your desktop or notebook, there can be other processes which can interfere with your measurement including system ones. Second thing, there is HW itself. Moder CPUs have many cool features which control performance and power consumption. They can boost performance for a short time before overheat, they can boost performance when there is not work on other CPUs on the same chip or other hyper thread on the same CPU. On another hand, they can enter power saving mode when there is not enough work and CPU doesn't react fast enough to the sudden change. It is hard to tell if it is your case, but it is naive to thing previous work or lack of it can't affect your measurement. You should always take care to measure in steady state for long enough time (seconds at least) and remove as much as possible other things which could affect your measurement. (And do not forget GC in Erlang as well.)